# Login with Google button - unable to get user first name, last name, etc except the user email id

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-signin, hybridauth

I am using Hybridauth 3.9. to add "Login with Google button" on my website. After the user login is success, I am not able to fetch their firstName, lastName, etc. However I can fetch their email id only.

**NOTE**: My publishing status is "Testing" in Google Cloud OAuth consent screen. I hope this is not the reason.

Working code sample:

```
$userProfile = $adapter->getUserProfile(); 
echo json_encode($userProfile);

//I am only getting the email id of the user. Rest are null.
{"identifier":"*****3478","webSiteURL":null,"profileURL":null,"photoURL":"https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/a-\/ACB-R5STKfcxZY0D0fSaRRCvuV0bYbhFLM0bjxxwAERB=s96-c","displayName":null,"description":null,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"gender":null,"language":null,"age":null,"birthDay":null,"birthMonth":null,"birthYear":null,"email":"myemailid@gmail.com","emailVerified":"myemailid@gmail.com","phone":null,"address":null,"country":null,"region":null,"city":null,"zip":null,"data":[]}
```

Minimal reproducible example

```
require 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
use Hybridauth\Hybridauth;

$config = [
    'callback' => 'https://path/to/hybridauth/examples/example_07/callback.php',
    'providers' => [
        'Google' => [
            'enabled' => true,
            'keys' => [
                'id' => '...',
                'secret' => '...',
            ],
            'scope' => 'email',
        ],
    ],
];

$hybridauth = new Hybridauth($config);
$adapters = $hybridauth->getConnectedAdapters();

<?php foreach ($hybridauth->getProviders() as $name) : ?>
    <?php if (!isset($adapters[$name])) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="javascript:auth_popup('<?php print $name ?>');">
                Sign in with <?php print $name ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php if ($adapters) : ?>
    <h1>You are logged in:</h1>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($adapters as $name => $adapter) : ?>
            echo $adapter->getUserProfile()->firstName;// getting null here
            echo $adapter->getUserProfile()->email;// email is echoing fine
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<script>
        function auth_popup(provider) {
            var authWindow = window.open('https://www.*****.com/social_login_callback?provider=' + provider, 'authWindow', 'width=600,height=400,scrollbars=yes');
            window.closeAuthWindow = function () {
              authWindow.close();
            }

            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

callback.php

```
<?php
require 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Hybridauth\Exception\Exception;
use Hybridauth\Hybridauth;
use Hybridauth\HttpClient;
use Hybridauth\Storage\Session;

$config = [
    'callback' => 'https://path/to/hybridauth/examples/example_07/callback.php',
    'providers' => [
        'Google' => [
            'enabled' => true,
            'keys' => [
                'id' => '...',
                'secret' => '...',
            ],
            'scope' => 'email',
        ],
];

try {

    $hybridauth = new Hybridauth($config);
    $storage = new Session();
    $error = false;

    //
    // Event 1: User clicked SIGN-IN link
    //
    if (isset($_GET['provider'])) {
        // Validate provider exists in the $config
        if (in_array($_GET['provider'], $hybridauth->getProviders())) {
            // Store the provider for the callback event
            $storage->set('provider', $_GET['provider']);
        } else {
            $error = $_GET['provider'];
        }
    }
    //
    // Event 2: Provider returns via CALLBACK
    //
    if ($provider = $storage->get('provider')) {

        $hybridauth->authenticate($provider);
        $storage->set('provider', null);

        // Retrieve the provider record
        $adapter = $hybridauth->getAdapter($provider);
        $userProfile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
        $accessToken = $adapter->getAccessToken();

        // add your custom AUTH functions (if any) here
        // ...
        $data = [
            'token' => $accessToken,
            'identifier' => $userProfile->identifier,
            'email' => $userProfile->email,
            'first_name' => $userProfile->firstName,
            'last_name' => $userProfile->lastName,
            'photoURL' => strtok($userProfile->photoURL, '?'),
        ];
        // ...

        // Close pop-up window
        echo "
            <script>
                if (window.opener.closeAuthWindow) {
                    window.opener.closeAuthWindow();
                }
            </script>";

    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Where does adapter come from can you give us a [example]

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Full example code is here - https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/tree/master/examples/example_07

Comment: You need to include a [example] in your question.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Question is updated with mre

Comment: Seems like few devs here on Stackoverflow who tried/used Hyridauth :-(